# Identificar mayúsculas y minúsculas al elegir opción en un menú

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Intenté de la siguiente manera y no funciona.

Dentro de un switch:

```
case 'A'|'a':
cout<<"ingrese V: "; cin>>v1; cout<<"ingrese R: "; cin>>r1;
ires1=v1/r1; cout<<"I es igual a: "<<ires1<<" A.\n"; break;
```

Al ingresar a minuscúla todo bien, pero al ingresar mayúscula:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Se muestra el default.

Comment: En C/C++/C# y demás lenguajes que sigan la línea C el o lógo es || (dos pipes) no uno solo.
Acá está misma pregunta en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513585/test-for-multiple-cases-in-a-switch-like-an-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para los switch puedes omitir el `break` y se continuara ejecutando el codigo de el caso siguiente. En este caso puedes aprovecharlo de esta manera:

```
  switch (condicion) {
  case 'a':
  case 'A':
    // Tu codigo
    break;
  case 'b':
  case 'B':
    // Tu codigo
    break;

  // Etc...
  }
```